# Find rows in data that are statistically different from the mean

Tags: statistical-significance, outliers, rare-events

I have the following data for various event locations. Each event can either be a success or failure (binary values). Thus the mean = percentage of successes.
The data represent the history of events

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}\rm Event\ location&\rm Number\ of\ events &\rm Mean\\\hline
A & 10 & 0.5\\
B & 2 & 1\\
C & 1 & 0\\
D & 100 & 0.3\\
E & 1 & 0\\
F & 1 & 1\\...&...&...\end{array}\\$$

I am looking for a way to find event locations whose chance of success in future events is low.

I am thinking of calculating the confidence in each locations success rate based on the sample of that location.

For example, having a location with only 1 or 2 events with either 0% or 100% success rate is likely as there are lots of such locations. However, a location with 100s of events but the mean very different from the overall mean is rare.

I am thinking of using the *t*-test to compare the mean of the event location with the overall mean and variance of the population.

Is there a better or another way to do this than the *t*-test? I feel this should be a common use case, find samples which are very different from others.

**EDIT:**
I found an option is to do a scipy.stats.binom_test on each row and use the p-value to find cases with high confidence. Still not sure if that is the best or the only way.

Comment: Could you help us make sense of the apparent contradiction between the assertions that "the data represent the entire population" and "events are drawn from a differently behaving population"?  Either the data are the entire population or they are drawn from other population(s), but it is difficult to see how both models could pertain at the same time.  Did you intend this to mean that the data are a *sample* but it's the only sample you can obtain?

Comment: The table captures every event that happened.

However, events at different locations could behave differently. For example, Events in New York may be more likely to be successful than events in San Francisco. 

I want to find locations where the events are least likely to be successful.

I can't just use the lowest rate, because I need to take into account the number of events at that locations. Locations with 1 event can have 100% failure rate purely by chance but that does not mean I have high confidence that events there fail

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It gets to the heart of the matter: if these are *all* the events that ever could happen, you have the entire population and there is no statistical variation: you can just rank the locations by failure rates: they are what they are. If instead you anticipate future events, then you have a *sample* that is subject to statistical fluctuations and, if you want to make inferences or predictions about *other* events, then indeed you have to account for the numbers of events at the locations. It *sounds* like you intend the latter, but you haven't actually said so.

Comment: You are correct. I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: If we treat the overall mean as pretty much known (its standard error is presumably quite small), you might consider an upper one-sided CI for the probability of success for each sample (perhaps using something like the rule of three for the zero success cases). If the upper limit of the CI on $p$ is still sufficiently low, you've probably observed enough to conclude it really is low.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a binomial test for each site as you describe. Take the overall proportion as an estimate of the mean and then calculate the p-value for each site that the true probability at that site is the same as the overall mean. Display interest in any site with a p-value less than 0.01. I suggest taking a smaller significance level than the classic 0.05 because you are doing multiple testing.

You could also analyse your data as a 2 by n contingency table, where n is the number of sites.

However, these approaches test whether all sites are identical against the hypothesis that at least one of them is different. Is this a reasonable hypothesis? I would expect the locations to be different. The question is: are some locations more extremely different than others? To address this possibility, you could model the data with a beta binomial distribution: assume that each location has its own success probability, but these probabilities have a beta distribution. You can fit the model using [R package bbmle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/index.html). The vignette for that package contains a useful introduction to the betabinomial and a carefully worked example.

The beta distribution has two parameters, p and theta. p is the overall proportion and theta is a measure of dispersion -- or how different the locations can reasonably be expected to be.

Once you have estimated the parameters of the beta binomial, you can determine which of your locations are outliers with respect to that distribution. Note that you can fit a beta-binomial with a different number of events for each location, as you have here.

If the beta-binomial is a good fit for your data, it will provide a more conservative model for the situation that you have than the binomial distribution. The beta-binomial allows that different locations may have slightly different success rates, but constrains those success rates to lie, typically, within a certain range. Only locations with success rates that are implausible with respect to the beta-binomial will be deemed outliers.